# Mathjax-react2 displaying wrong output on screen

Tags: reactjs, components, output, mathjax

i have a problem, in my react app, i have a mathjax context and node, but when i insert even an empty string " ", it outputs " ,". (With the coma)Can someone tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: FIXED 
added this into the mathjax.component props
options={ {
                                            asciimath2jax: {
                                                 useMathMLspacing: true,
                                                 delimiters: [["$$","$$"]],
                                                 preview: "none",
                                            }
                                        } }

Comment: Next time consider attaching a link reproducing the problem. A gist might be enough for something short, github for a full project or codesandbox if you can. Just make sure you shave the code down to only reproduce the problem.